# Spring cache logging on @Cacheable hit

Tags: java, spring, slf4j, spring-cache

Currently I am working with a Spring Cache and the `@Cacheable`/`@CacheEvict` annotations.

I would like to get some sort of a console log statement like `"INFO: i got those values from the cache, NOT from the host. awesome"`

Is there a clean and easy way to do this? We are using `slf4j` apparently btw, if that is of any interest.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Spring itself logs some of its Caching Abstractions behaviors under the `org.springframework.cache` logger in `trace` level. So, if you append logs under the `org.springframework.cache` logger to an appropriate appender, you would have some useful information on, say, the console. If you're using Logback, you could use something like the following in your `logback.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework.cache" level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

With this configuration, you should see something like following on your console:

> Cache entry for key 'Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: null]'
>   found in cache 'persons'

Comment: that helped me find the similar config in our project setup. thanks :)

Answer (score 70):

And for Spring Boot 2 you can add in your application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.cache=TRACE
```

Answer (score 3):

if u use application.yml AND spring-boot 2

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.cache: TRACE
```

do not set DEBUG level, it works only for TRACE

for application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.cache=TRACE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enable trace level logging.

Eg., in application.properties put 'trace=true'.

[Spring logging documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a good idea to open trace log all the time, even it is only for cache log.
The better way is, EHcache has this hit/miss metrics already, you can get it by `JMX` or `spring boot actuator`.

To use by JMX, you can refer [this](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-hibernate-ehcache-caching)

To use `Spring Boot Actuator`, you can refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.12.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html).

Comment: Definitely agree except for if it would be done on local developers machine. However this is very good and valuable hint, how to log and monitor cache behavior.